# anchor element not changing to inline on hover

Tags: hover, anchor, css

code below not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
li:hover
{
display:inline;
font-size:30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

i supposed they should have been arranged themselves horizontally on hovering.

link- http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_display_inline_list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply it to all `li` on hover of the `ul`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/26/

```
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
ul:hover li
{
display:inline;
font-size:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are going right direction.

Do you want to rearage position of menu items when user put mouse cursor on it?
It can not work. If user put mouse on "About" item, it disapears and apperas in first line with other elements, but it loses hover state and apears back, under the cursor, so it get back hover state and move to first line again in loop....

Comment: the other think is, hover on elements that not an anchor is not working properly in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Though this effect is a little weird, try this way:

```
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

ul:hover li { /*<<<here's the magic!*/
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

The way you've tried, you're not changing the anchor to be inline, but the list item. The problem is that you're setting the display: inline to only one "li", this is not applied to the others items. You need to make all of your "li" inline on the hover of your whole list (ul).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. Are you trying to inline your links? If so, try this for your css markup..

```
<style>
ul { list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0; }
ul li { display: inline !important; }
ul li a:link, ul li a:visited { text-decoration: none; color: #1122CC; }
ul li a:hover, ul li a:active { text-decoration: underline; }
</style>
```